# Use data from previous date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table (all values are kinda random, table is huge, but algorithm should be same, for example):

| date | install_date | installs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-27 | 2022-01-14 | 50 |
| 2022-01-27 | 2022-01-13 | 100 |
| 2022-01-26 | 2022-01-13 | 100 |
| 2022-01-26 | 2022-01-12 | 200 |

I want to get this table:

| date | install_date | installs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-27 | 2022-01-14 | 50 |
| 2022-01-27 | 2022-01-13 | 100 |
| 2022-01-27 | 2022-01-12 | 200 |

At report date `2022-01-27` I've two install_dates, but I also want to put `installs,install_date` from previous date `2022-01-26` and write it as `2022-01-27`.
How can I make this?
My attempt

```
SELECT
date,
install_date,
installs
FROM table

UNION ALL

SELECT 
date,
install_date,
installs
FROM table
WHERE date = date - INTERVAL '1 DAY' and install_date NOT IN (SELECT install_date FROM table WHERE date = date) --NOT IN to avoid dublicates?
```

**EDIT**

`report_date` (renamed from date) stores information abouts installs: date (`install_date`) and amount (`installs`). Each `report_date` contains data *snapshots* for 15 days ago and 50 days ahead
What does it mean? If I'll go to my table and run `SELECT WHERE report_date = '2022-01-27'` I will get rows with `install_date` from `2022-01-13` to  `2022-03-18`. I need to buld reports per month, so at `report_date = '2022-01-27'` I need to see rows with `install_date` from `2022-01-01` to `2022-01-31`. I can find this missing information if I go back a day. At `report_date = '2022-01-26'` I will find information for `install_date = 2022-01-12` and so on. At `report_date = '2022-01-27'` I don't need information about `install_dates` that already exists for this date from other dates. So, look at these new tables.

Source:

```
|report_date |install_date  |installs  |
| --------   | ------------ | -----    |
| 2022-01-27 | 2022-01-14   | 10       |
| 2022-01-27 | 2022-01-13   | 20       |
| 2022-01-26 | 2022-01-14   | 10       | -- i don't need this row for report_date 2022.01.27, because its clearly a duplicate (for this report_date I already have this install_date)
| 2022-01-26 | 2022-01-13   | 20       | -- i don't need this row for report_date 2022.01.27, because its clearly a duplicate
| 2022-01-26 | 2022-01-12   | 30       | -- i need this row for report_date 2022.01.27, because at this date I don't have data with install_date
| 2022-01-25 | 2022-01-14   | 10       | -- i don't need this row for report_date 2022.01.27 and 2022.01.26, because its clearly a duplicate 
| 2022-01-25 | 2022-01-13   | 20       | -- i don't need this row for report_date 2022.01.27 and 2022.01.26, because its clearly a duplicate 
| 2022-01-25 | 2022-01-12   | 30       | -- i don't need this row for report_date 2022.01.27 and 2022.01.26, because its clearly a duplicate 
| 2022-01-25 | 2022-01-11   | 40       | -- i need this row for report_date 2022.01.27 and 2022.01.26
```

So for this only three different report_dates I expect to get this table:

```
|report_date |install_date  |installs  |
| --------   | ------------ | -----    |
| 2022-01-27 | 2022-01-14   | 10       |
| 2022-01-27 | 2022-01-13   | 20       |
| 2022-01-27 | 2022-01-12   | 30       |
| 2022-01-27 | 2022-01-11   | 40       |
| 2022-01-26 | 2022-01-14   | 10       |
| 2022-01-26 | 2022-01-13   | 20       | 
| 2022-01-26 | 2022-01-12   | 30       | 
| 2022-01-26 | 2022-01-11   | 40       | 
| 2022-01-25 | 2022-01-14   | 10       |
| 2022-01-25 | 2022-01-13   | 20       | 
| 2022-01-25 | 2022-01-12   | 30       | 
| 2022-01-25 | 2022-01-11   | 40       |
```

So, I need to take `report_date` and add missing `install_dates` from previous 15 days.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me, what you want, but maybe change `date = date - INTERVAL '1 DAY'` to `date = current_date - 1`? (Btw: "date" is a horrible name for a column. For one because it's a keyword, but more importantly it doesn't document what kind of date that is. A "due date"? A "registration date"? An "order date"?

Comment: The fact is that the dates are splitted in such a way that not all install_dates are present there, so I need to go back a day ago and collect the received data. On January 27th, I see two lines (for January 13th and 14th), and to see that the data for January 12th I have to lower one day ago (this is the date column) and the data for ('2022-01-26', '2022-01 -12 ') should be saved as ('2022-01-27', 2022-01-12')

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I also feel discomfort looking at things named after their types (`create table date(date date);`) but I wonder exactly how problematic this is. I think if the table name is `order` and column is `id` it's not uncommon to leave it as that, without renaming to `order_id`. If the table is `order` and column is `date`, `order_date` doesn't add much clarity. I'm wondering what would be an example to show someone, to discourage them from using type names as identifiers. Or is it just a "this can't possibly be healthy, this is looking for trouble" knee-jerk reaction.

Comment: But is the "date" in a table named order the "order date"? Or the "fulfillment date"? Or the "delivery date"? Or the "payment due date"?  Or the "delivery date"?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's hard not to agree on the clarity/verbosity part of the question but what about "type name as identifier" problem? `create table order_deliveries(date date, id serial primary key, order_id bigint...)` might not be the best example, but I'm sure we could find one where column named "date" combined with the table name is unambiguous in regards to its contents. In that scenario, other than said clarity, what would be the reason to prevent column name coinciding with type name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to duplicate all records and show them with one day later date. I assume you don't want the latest date to be duplicated, or any other for which there's no "next day" to pair with. I also assume you do want to see `2022-01-26` again separately.

```sql
create table my_table(date date, install_date date, installs int);
insert into my_table (date,install_date,installs) values
('2022-01-27','2022-01-14', 50),
('2022-01-27','2022-01-13', 100),
('2022-01-26','2022-01-13', 100),
('2022-01-26','2022-01-12', 200);

select * 
from (
    SELECT
      date,
      install_date,
      installs
    FROM my_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
      date +1,
      install_date,
      installs
    FROM my_table m1
    where exists (
       select True 
       from my_table m2 
       where m2.date = m1.date+'1 day'::interval )
) a 
order by date desc;
--    date    | install_date | installs
--------------+--------------+----------
-- 2022-01-27 | 2022-01-12   |      200
-- 2022-01-27 | 2022-01-13   |      100
-- 2022-01-27 | 2022-01-13   |      100
-- 2022-01-27 | 2022-01-14   |       50
-- 2022-01-26 | 2022-01-12   |      200
-- 2022-01-26 | 2022-01-13   |      100
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/vWhUOPJ_) and some comments about your query:

```sql
SELECT
  date,
  install_date,
  installs
FROM my_table
UNION ALL
SELECT --will never return any rows to union with because of an impossible where
  date,
  install_date,
  installs
FROM my_table
WHERE date=date-INTERVAL '1 DAY'--Always false, it's the same field.`where 2=2-1`
  and install_date NOT IN (
  SELECT install_date 
  FROM my_table 
  WHERE date = date --Always true, it's the same field. Same as `where 2=2`.
  )
```

Comment: You understood me right :)
It works fine! What will change, if I also want to add data from `2022-01-25` (two days ago) to `2022-01-27` and `2022-01-26`? So, `2022-01-25` date stores data for install_date `2022-01-11`. I tried to add another union with (date +2) and 2 day interval, but now i see duplicates(

Comment: @takotsubo This already adds `2022-01-25` to `2022-01-26`, because `2022-01-25` will be duplicated with one day added. If you also want to multiply the records as 2 days later, another union with changed intervals [should work](https://dbfiddle.uk/z0TDwc8M). But taking a step back for a bit: what is it that you're trying to achieve? Are you trying to get a stepping/window sum of installs? What do `date`, `install_date` and `installs` correspond to? If we're only troubleshooting just one step of some longer process, consider that there might be an easier way to achieve your final goal.

Comment: Thank you! I updated my question. Tried my best to describe it.

Comment: @takotsubo After the update, it sounds like you're just trying to get [`select distinct install_date, installs from my_table;`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT). Is this monthly report *monthly* in terms of `report_date`/"snapshot date", or in terms of `install_date`? Are you trying to find an list all unique dates and installs in a given month, for all months, or maybe get a sum per month?

Comment: Monthly in terms of report_date and install_date. 
I GROUP by `report_date` and `install_date`, but `install_date` I CAST to month like (202201). I have another table table2 that contains column `report_month` and `report_date`. I JOIN table1 from example ON t2.report_month = t1.report_month (extract month from install_date) AND t2.report_date = t1.report_date
Maybe it sounds weird, but I've this task...

Comment: Unique dates in a given month. So, If `report_date` in january (27, 15, 1 etc) i need `install_date` for every day inside this month. I don't neet to look ahead from 01.01.2022, because every `report_date` contains info 50 days ahead (install_date), but only 15 days ago. So after 15.01.2022 I will not found all `install_dates` and I'll have to go some `report_date` ago to find it from another report_date.

Comment: @takotsubo Use `date_trunc('month',install_date)::date`. It will keep the timestamp/date type and hold both the year and the month - extracting both or constructing an abstract `text` or `int`-based format for `202201` to group by, is less practical. Some questions: **1.** What's the purpose of `table2`? **2.** If no report mentions installs on a given date (say there's a hole on Jan 10th), do you skip it, show the date but with `null` installs, or show it with 0 installs? **3.** Are you trying to stretch the reports to full months, getting missing days from the most recent, previous reports?

Comment: 1. table2 contains additional info about apps (column app_id in both tables), has columns report_date, report_month and in-app purchases 2. 0 installs 3. They are used for monthly reports, and i need these dates for correct join later. On each day (report_date) of the month, all install_date must be available. Each report_date contains information up to 15 days ago, so to fill rest of month (starting from 15 day of each month) i need to go back and take these values from prev days