# Avoid correlated subquery and one to one code

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've a table where some days are skipped. To fill these days I use information from previous days.  One *arrival_date* contains information for one week (from Monday to Friday). So for this I check all five previous days and grab data from them.
I found solution from one [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74569999/use-data-from-previous-date) on stackoverflow. My task is very very similar. Query:

```
SELECT 
    arrival_date,
    order_id,
    order_date,
FROM orders orders
UNION ALL
SELECT
    arrival_date + INTERVAL '1 day',
    order_id,
    order_date
FROM orders ord1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT true FROM orders ord2 WHERE ord2.arrival_date = ord1.arrival_date + INTERVAL '1 day')
UNION ALL
SELECT
    arrival_date + INTERVAL '2 day',
    order_id,
    order_date
FROM orders ord1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT true FROM orders ord2 WHERE ord2.arrival_date = ord1.arrival_date + INTERVAL '2 day')
UNION ALL
SELECT
    arrival_date + INTERVAL '3 day',
    order_id,
    order_date
FROM orders ord1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT true FROM orders ord2 WHERE ord2.arrival_date = ord1.arrival_date + INTERVAL '3 day')
UNION ALL
SELECT
    arrival_date + INTERVAL '4 day',
    order_id,
    order_date
FROM orders ord1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT true FROM orders ord2 WHERE ord2.arrival_date = ord1.arrival_date + INTERVAL '4 day')
UNION ALL
SELECT
    arrival_date + INTERVAL '5 day',
    order_id,
    order_date
FROM orders ord1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT true FROM orders ord2 WHERE ord2.arrival_date = ord1.arrival_date + INTERVAL '5 day')
```

Can I somehow replace these 5 UNIONS? It looks like one to one code, only the number of days changes. And any way how to replace correlated subquery with *WHERE EXISTS*?

Comment: I believe, there are several ways. However, it would make things easier if you could provide an example and expected output.

Comment: Assuming `arrival_date` is `date` type:`... where arrival_date <@  daterange((arrival_date + INTERVAL '1 day')::date, (arrival_date + interval '5 days')::date, '[]');`